# Searching in two HashSets

Tags: c#, search, hashset

I have this method:

```
bool CheckIfAvailable(HashSet<int> hayStack1, HashSet<int> hayStack2, int needle) {
}
```

And I'm trying to do the following: if `hayStack1` and `hayStack2` are both `null` the method should return `true`, if one of them is not `null` the `needle` should be in it to return `true`, if both of them are not `null` the `needle` can be in either one of them or both to be `true`.

I can do that but my approach is very messy, is there any way to do it in an elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool CheckIfAvailable(HashSet<int> hayStack1, HashSet<int> hayStack2, int needle)
{
    bool? s1 = hayStack1?.Contains(needle);
    bool? s2 = hayStack2?.Contains(needle);
    if (s1 ?? s2 ?? true) return true; 
    return s2 == true; 
}
```

Explanation:

`if (s1 ?? s2 ?? true)` only becomes true when:

> `s1 == s2 == null` Or `s1 == true || (s1 == null && s2 == true)`

`return s2 == true;` Since `s1` may become false then we check if `s2` is true or not.

Which can be replaced with single return statement.

```
bool CheckIfAvailable(HashSet<int> hayStack1, HashSet<int> hayStack2, int needle)
{
    bool? s1 = hayStack1?.Contains(needle);
    bool? s2 = hayStack2?.Contains(needle);
    return (s1 ?? s2 ?? true) || s2 == true;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Can you explain further why `return s2 == true;` is necessary? Is it related to concurrency?

Comment: @TadijaBagarić This is for the case when s1 == false and s2 == true.

Comment: @TadijaBagarić if `s1` becomes false the expression becomes false without looking into `s2`. therefore its necessary to check `s2 == true`

Comment: Ah right. Cool use of c# 6.0 - My job security is looking forward to using this code style!

Answer (score 1):

```
bool CheckIfAvailable(HashSet<int> hayStack1, HashSet<int> hayStack2, int needle) 
{
    if(hayStack1 == null && hayStack2 == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(hayStack1 != null && hayStack1.Contains(needle))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(hayStack2 != null && hayStack2.Contains(needle))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or

```
bool CheckIfAvailable(HashSet<int> hayStack1, HashSet<int> hayStack2, int needle) 
{
    bool setsAreNull = hayStack1 == null && hayStack2 == null;
    bool hayStack1ContainsNeedle = hayStack1 != null && hayStack1.Contains(needle);
    bool hayStack2ContainsNeedle = hayStack2 != null && hayStack2.Contains(needle);

    return setsAreNull || hayStack1ContainsNeedle  || hayStack2ContainsNeedle ;
}
```